# Insert DateTime with Symfony / MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, symfony, datetime, doctrine, datetime2

I try to insert Datetime in a MSSQL database but the column is in datetime.
I know Symfony accept only datetime2, but i can't update the structure of this database but i need to update data with Symfony.

How can I do this ? My Entity is this

```
<?php

/**
 * RendezVous
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="RENDEZ_VOUS", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_292A17E650EAE44", columns={"id_utilisateur"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RendezVous
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_heure", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateHeure;

    /**
     * @var \Utilisateur
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Utilisateur")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_utilisateur", referencedColumnName="id_utilisateur")
     * })
     */
    private $idUtilisateur;

    public function getDateHeure(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->dateHeure;
    }

    public function setDateHeure(?\DateTime $dateHeure): self
    {
        $this->dateHeure = $dateHeure;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I try to create new DateTime() and just set the timestamp but it doesn't work because it's not compatible.

I try to use ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') on the DateTime but it return me a string value and my entity attempt a DateTimeInterface.

I try to declare my column as a string column (in my sql table this is a datetime) to use the ->format() and insert with a string but it doesn't work because my sql table attempt a DateTime value

Comment: I am not familiar with symfony but in many other languages you can do a cast as SQL data types specifically.  You can see if that is an option in symfony.

Comment: This seems like a [Doctrine issue](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3373). Note though that the proposed format string `'Y-m-d H:i:s.v'` is itself flawed because it's sensitive to the current `DATEFORMAT` setting when SQL Server tries to convert the formatted string back to a `datetime` type, and that can be fixed by including a `T` between the date and time portions, i.e.: `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v'`. Of course anything that's sending formatted strings over the wire instead of the proper scalar types is already a code smell.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning(enanglais) Thanks, with your format 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v' i've replace it and try something that i had already test but it works. I replaced in my entity datetime and DateTimeInterface by string and when i try so flush with a string it works so that's enough